# Printing hexadecimal Unicode code points with shell utilities like hexdump or xxd

Tags: bash, unicode

Bash 4.2 and zsh support `echo $'\u30a2'`, but are there alternatives to this using common shell utilities?

```
$ ruby -e 'puts ARGV[0].chars.map{|c|c.ord.to_s(16)}.join(" ")' aäア
61 e4 30a2 1d400
```

This doesn't work with U+10000 or characters above it:

```
$ printf %s aäア | iconv -f $(locale charmap) -t UTF-16BE | xxd -p
006100e430a2d835dc00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this function in https://raw.github.com/lhunath/scripts/master/bash/bashlib/bashlib:

```
hex() { 
  printf '%x' "'$1"
}
```

More examples:

```
$ printf %x\\n \'ア
7fc2
$ LC_CTYPE=C printf %x\\n \'ア
e3
$ printf %s $'  \n\n\\'|while IFS= read -r -d '' -n1 c;do printf %x\\n "'$c";done
20
20
a
a
5c
$ printf %s aäア|while IFS= read -r -d '' -n1 c;do printf '%s %x\n' "$c" "'$c";done
a 61
ä e4
ア 30a2
 1d400
```

This worked with the `printf` builtins in bash 4.2 and zsh 4.3.11 but not with the builtin `printf` in bash 3.2 or with OS X's `/usr/bin/printf`.

`-n1` reads one character at a time, and `-d ''` changes the delimiter from `\n` to `\0`, so `read` also includes linefeeds (but not NUL characters). The only option for `read` specified by POSIX is `-r`.

Answer (score 3):

A simple Python 2.7 script is able to do the job (call it a.py say) [script below assumes your shell encoding is UTF8 by default - you may have to change it if required]:

```
import sys

for i in unicode(sys.argv[1], 'utf-8'):
    print i.encode("utf_16_be").encode("hex")
```

Testing:

```
$ python a.py aäア
0061
00e4
30a2
d835dc00
```