# Strange ASCII response(chinese) when trying to replicate strlwr in codeblocks 13.12

Tags: c++, unicode, codeblocks, chinese-locale, extended-ascii

The following code gives a very strange result:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

ifstream f("f1.in");
ofstream g("f1.out");
char sir[255];
int i;

char strlwr(char sir[]) //if void nothing changes
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; sir[i] != NULL; i++) {
        sir[i] = tolower(sir[i]);
    }

    return 0;  //if instead of 0 is 1 it will kinda work , but strlwr(sir) still needs to   be displayed
}

int main()
{
    f.get(sir, 255);
    g << sir << '\n'; // without '\n' strlwr will no more maters
    g << strlwr(sir);
    g << sir;
    return 0;
}
```

f1.in:

```
JHON HAS A COW
```

f1.out:

```
䡊乏䠠十䄠䌠坏 
桪湯栠獡愠挠睯
```

It shows this only when I am using just CAPS.
I am using Code::Blocks 13.12 on Ubuntu 14, European version.
I would be very interested in knowing why it shows this.
I am interested in knowing if it gives you the same thing.

Comment: What's the contents of `f1.in`?  It sounds like it might be the result of [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).  (i.e. The text is ASCII, but your terminal or output parser thinks it's UTF-8)

Comment: The conent is "JHON HAS A COW" all in caps and the result is shown in f1.out . I think that the ASCII value is changed but I do not know where in the program , and why if I remove that '\n' (endl) the thing does not happen anymore. Mojibake might be related to this , but I do not think that it is the problem.

Comment: What are you using to view the output with?  `cat f1.out` or using a text editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations!  You've discovered [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)!  Your output text is 100% correct, but whatever your viewing it with is interpreting it as unicode.

If you convert the unicode output into their hex numerical values, the issue will become clear.  (Code borrowed from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409595/printing-hexadecimal-unicode-code-points-with-shell-utilities-like-hexdump-or-xx).)

```
$ cat unicode.txt
䡊乏䠠十䄠䌠坏
桪湯栠獡愠挠睯

$ cat unicode.txt | while IFS= read -r -d '' -n1 c; do printf "%02X\n" "'$c"; done
484A
4E4F
4820
5341
4120
4320
574F
0A
686A
6E6F
6820
7361
6120
6320
776F
0A
```

The second command reads the file character by character and prints the *little endian* form in hex.  The reason each character is two bytes of data is because the input is understood to be UTF-16, a 2-byte encoding.

If you reinterpret the hex output as single byte ASCII instead (and correct for endianness) you can see that your program did work:

```
$ cat unicode.txt | while IFS= read -r -d '' -n1 c; do printf "%02X\n" "'$c"; done
484A ; JH
4E4F ; ON
4820 ;  H
5341 ; AS
4120 ;  A
4320 ;  C
574F ; OW
0A   ; \n
686A ; jh
6E6F ; on
6820 ;  h
7361 ; as
6120 ;  a
6320 ;  c
776F ; ow
0A   ; \n
```

To determine if the issue is your C++ program or your viewing program, try running the following command `xxd f1.out`.  If it looks like ASCII, then it's your viewing programs fault.  Otherwise, it's your program's fault and you should look into [setlocale](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/setlocale) and/or opening your output file in binary mode.

Either way, you should probably change `g<<strlwr(sir);` to just `strlwr(sir);`.  Currently it's adding a NULL byte to your output which is probably unintended.

Comment: I saw the thing with strlwr() but I did not understand  why if I change g<<strlwr(sir) to just strlwr(sir) everything works as it should be working  , I thought that  NULL byte should have shown me a 0 , at most, but  I think that this means that that NULL byte between the 2 rows is changing everything .

Comment: @George - *Normally* it would have written a `0` but you've defined the function to return a `char`, not an `int`.  Although the value of a `(char)0` and `(int)0` are the same, when it comes to writing them to a file they're handled differently.